# What am I doing wrong with this redirect 301 code?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I am trying to create a 301 redirect from my .htaccess file to my ad publisher's dynamic ads.txt

[www.wegamedaily.com/ads.txt](http://www.wegamedaily.com/ads.txt) is supposed to redirect to //config.playwire.com/dyn_ads/1025181/74787/ads.txt

For some reason, it doesn't. There's no 404, just a blank page. It almost doesn't appear to load properly. The only file I have in my root directory is an empty ads.txt file.

Here's the code I used. What am I doing wrong?[301 code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zE56a.jpg)

Any help very appreciated because between my hosting and the ad publisher we are going around in circles.

I've tried moving the location of the redirect URL, deleting the ads.txt and reuploading a new one. I unistalled the redirect WP plug-in incase there was a clash of some sort. No luck.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: `Redirect` matches against the URL path only, not against a full, absolute one.

Comment: And your substitution URL starts with a slash - so the current hostname and protocol will be prefixed; which is not what you want here.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your responses. This was eventually solved by moving the Redirect to within the "Ifmodule rewrite.c". By placing it outside, either above or below that rewrite rule, it did not function properly.